# Manipulate SVG path length with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg, path

How can I adjust the length of the blue line (atm 100%) to 70%?

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/7FP3J/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="p0">0%</div>
<div id="p100">100%</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
    <path fill="none" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" stroke="#0074c4" d="M80,80 A80,80 0 1,180.61117636732928,100.45116865416591" stroke-width="3" id="test"/>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
#p0 {
  color: #0074c4;
  left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
}
#p100 {
  color: #0074c4;
  left: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 144px;
}
```

**JS**

```
setCircleTo(70);

function setCircleTo(percent)
{
    // percent   
    // $('#test').attr('d','') 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the dash array trick.

```
function setCircleTo(percent)
{
    var path = $('#test').get(0);
    var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
    var adjustedLen = percent * pathLen / 100;
    path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', adjustedLen+' '+pathLen);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7FP3J/12/)

Comment: Thanks fpr this nice solution but the small line on the left side should be blue (all the time)  :/ http://jsfiddle.net/7FP3J/21/

Comment: Do you mean like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/7FP3J/23/  If not, then you might have to edit your question with a better description of what you want, because I am not following.